# Contact form 7 thank you page redirection on new window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I set up a thank you page redirection which is working fine. But I want to open the redirected URL in a new window. How can I do that?

Here is the code -

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );

function redirect_cf7() {
    <script>
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            location = 'https://example.com/thank-you/';
        }, false );
    </script>
}
```

Please help me to achieve that without any plugin.

For your reference, here is the official documentation:
[Contact Form 7 DOM Events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it working. Here is the code which solved the issue:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );

function redirect_cf7() { ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            _location = 'https://example.com/thank-you/';
            window.open(_location, "MsgWindow");
        }, false );
    </script>
<?php }
```

Thanks to all of you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be this will help you out Now the page will open in another window

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Which type of event is this wpcf7mailsent ??

Comment: Fires when an AJAX form submission has completed successfully, and mail has been sent.

Comment: The above code which I posted here in the question is working fine & the event is also firing. But the main problem is that it is opening the URL in same window, which I want to change to a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
     document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        location =   window.open('https://example.com/thank-you/', '_blank' );
    }, false );
```

This is local snippet prove that all work(oblivius don't work with snippet but you need to run with local server):

```js
function redirect(){

 location =   window.open('https://google.com/', '_blank' );

}
```

```html
<button onclick="redirect()">redirect</button>
```

Comment: you change `window.open(location` <- to your link and `getElementById` with your id link?

Comment: Nope, it's not working also. After doing this it returns a wrong URL which is something like **https://example.com/form-page/null**. Which is a wrong URL & throwing 404 error.

Comment: The event is firing when the form is successfully submitted & the mail also sent, as per official documentation.

Comment: it doesn't matter when the command is launched, your question was: _How can I open a link in another tab without using plugins?_  `window.open` is the answer

Comment: Yes that's true